# É possível chamar um método dentro de outra instância?

Tags: android, kotlin

eu tenho uma `Activity` que mostra um `AlertDialog` personalizado, como a classe da `Activity` estava meio grande coloquei a chamada desse Alert em outra classe em um método estático. Ao clicar em um certo botão do Alert (ou ao fechá-lo) eu queria que um método da classe Activity fosse executado (o que se encarrega de atualizar um ListView), mas para alterar o ListView ele precisaria ser chamado na instância em que a Activity está rodando. Com o `context` da Activity ou de algum outro meio é possível usar aquele método? Pensei em fazer essa classe do AlertDialog como uma `partial class` da Activity, mas pelo que vi isso não é possível em Kotlin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode passar uma função para ser executada quando o botão for clicado.

Na sua classe com método estático:

```
fun buildDialog(context: Context, action: () -> Unit) {
  AlertDialog.Builder(context)
      .setTitle("Title")
      .setMessage("Message")
      .setPositiveButton("Confirm", { _, _ ->
        action()
      })
}
```

E na sua Activity, ao instanciar o dialog:

```
fun buildMyDialog() {

  Helper.buildDialog(this, {
    // UPDATE MY LIST
    // DO STUFF
  })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Leonardo, 
Eu tinha uma solução parecida com a vossa no Java, ao migrar para o Kotlin, eu migrei o que pude para extensions (criei um diretorio com este nome para colocar todas as extensoes)

Para alertas sem precisar passar o contexto, arquivo extensions/Activity.kt:

```
    // Alertas

    var _alertDialogExtActivity: AlertDialog? = null // Para somente permitir um alerta ativo

    fun Activity.extAlerta(mensagem: String, callbackOK: (() -> Unit)? = null) {

     // Mostra alerta

    if (_alertDialogExtActivity != null) { // Existe um dialogo ativo ?
       _alertDialogExtActivity!!.cancel()
       _alertDialogExtActivity!!.hide()
    }

    this.runOnUiThread {
        val alertDialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)

        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(mensagem)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("OK") { _, _ ->
                    if (callbackOK != null) {
                        callbackOK()
                    }
                }
        _alertDialogExtActivity = alertDialogBuilder.create()
        _alertDialogExtActivity!!.show()
    }

}
```